# Is there a way to have Windows Explorer List View display file numbers (as in a numbered list)?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

When in File Explorer's list view, the bottom left of the window shows that I have x items. Is there way to have one of the columns be the number of the item (1-x)?

I guess really this could be answered for any version of Windows, but I've only needed it recently.

I can do something similar in a word document rather trivially (turn a list of items into a numbered or bulleted list).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Is there way to have one of the columns be the number of the item (1-x)?

I don't know of any way to do this with Windows Explorer.

You can, however, easily do this with [XYplorer](http://www.xyplorer.com/), a portable file manager for windows:

[image]

Configured as "Views" > "Details" and columns "Line Numbers" and "Name" enabled:

[image]